# Backbone.js: my events would not fire! How can I fix this small code?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to learn **Backbone.js**. I've been stuck on this for a whole hour. I don't get why my event would not fire..

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/jancarlo000/ejn2J/

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/efefip/3/edit

**see ItemView** the one starting on this section:

```
var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({ ....
```

FULL CODE:

```
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({ defaults: { Task: 'Study!'} });
var List = Backbone.Collection.extend({});

var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    className: '',
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        window.list = new List();
        window.list.bind('add', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function(model, collection, options){
        var itemView = new ItemView({model:model});
        $(this.el).append(itemView.el);
        $('body').html(this.el);
        return this; 
    }
});

//-------------- PROBLEM HERE -------------------------------
var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    events: {
        "click #deleteMe":"deleteMe" //<-- this doesn't fire!
    },
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        $(this.el).append(this.model.get('Task') + 
                              '<button id="deleteMe">Delete Me</button>'); 
            //WHY WON'T THIS FIRE!!!
        return this;
    },
    deleteMe: function(e){
        console.log('called deleteMe');
        $(this.el).remove();
    }
});
//------------------------------------------------------------

$(function(){

var app = new MainView();
var first = new Item({Task:'Learn JavaScript'});
var second = new Item({Task:'Learn HTML5'});
var third = new Item({Task:'Learn Backbone.JS'});
var fourth = new Item({Task:'Learn .NET MVC'});
list.add([first, second, third, fourth]);

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your main view `render`, you use `$('body').html(this.el);` which replaces the views and their event handlers with unbound elements.

Removing this line and appending the main view el to the body in the initialize method gives the intended result

```
var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    className: '',
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        window.list = new List();
        window.list.bind('add', this.render, this);
         $('body').append(this.el);
    },
    render: function(model, collection, options){
        var itemView = new ItemView({model:model});
        $(this.el).append(itemView.el);
        console.log($(this.el));

        return this;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ejn2J/6/

And if I may, a few opinions

- don't create your Collection in your view, create it in your init code and pass it to your view, the view should not be responsible for creating the models/collections of your app and you may need to reference the collection somewhere else,
- your MainView render should be used to re-render the whole list, not a lone model: its purpose is to maintain the UI display of the collection, you probably will need at a later time to add/edit/delete a model and refresh its representation
- don't tie your MainView to the body in the view code, build the view in memory and then append its el to its parent, it's faster and much easier to move around at a later time

http://jsfiddle.net/ejn2J/7/

Comment: Thank you! This has helped me so much. I've been pulling my hair out for two hours already..

Comment: Mind if you could expand a bit as to why on your advices? Im barely moving to JS from .net and Backbone is a bit complicated.

Comment: @JanCarloViray, added some (short) explanations, you will have to do a bit of reading elsewhere to fit all the pieces together :) There are a lot of good questions on SO under the backbone.js tag that may help you.

Comment: thanks again and I appreciate it :) You're very thorough. I hope you could help me again maybe in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

This issue also can be solved by invoking this.delegateEvents(); after your view is built.